# docker PHP-APACHE "You don't have permission to access / on this server”

Tags: php, apache, docker

I'm using the official docker images for apache and php : https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ (the 5.6-apache tag)

I'm launching the container like this :

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name apache-php56 -v "/home/myUser/www":/var/www/html php:5.6-apache
```

Of course, I have all my code in "/home/myUser/www"

When I am in a directory with an index, it seems like apache is displaying the page pretty well. However if I am in a directory without index, apache tells me that I don't have permission to access.
I would like apache to show me the "classical" view when there is no index with the "Name   Last modified   Size    Description" and I can navigate through until I find an index.

I'm pretty sure this is a simple config in the default apache2.conf that forbid me but I have no idea which.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: I guess you're looking for https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

Comment: I guess this is close to the problem. In my apache2.conf there is : DirectoryIndex disabled AND DirectoryIndex index.php index.html . I removed the DirectoryIndex disabled but i still am forbidden :(

Comment: You'd need to restart the apache2 process after making that change since you don't appear to be adding your own config to the container, but that would potentially stop the container. Ideally, you want to copy the file with your changes, and then mount the config file as a volume in the right place for your updated config so it gets used instead of the default.

Comment: This is what I did. After modifying the file, I restarted apache (which restared the container). I started it again, check the apache2.conf (the line isn't here anymore) but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my symfony project while using docker. The problem was that the **.htaccess** file was missing in the **web** folder.
You can create one by your self or you can install **symfony/apache-pack** with composer if you use symfony.
An example .htaccess can be found in the [symfony documentation for web server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)